# how to calc the average of four calculated columns in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Following is a code snippet where I am trying to calculate, row by row, the average of the result of all four case statements.    If the AVG function is omitted, the report lists the four calculated columns correctly as four numbers.  But when run as is i get "error or missing database near "order_interval_using_pvs1_order_date"

Can someone show me how to calc the average as requested?  much thanks.

```
AVG(

    CASE 
     WHEN LAG(order_entry_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC) <> ""
     THEN JULIANDAY("orders_tbl"."order_entry_date") - JULIANDAY(LAG(order_entry_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC))
    END "order_interval_using_pvs1_order_date",
    
    CASE 
     WHEN LAG(order_entry_date,2) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC) <> ""
     THEN JULIANDAY(LAG( order_entry_date, 1 ) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id  ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC)) - JULIANDAY(LAG(order_entry_date,2) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC))
    END "order_interval_using_pvs2_order_date",
    
    CASE 
     WHEN LAG(order_entry_date,3) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC) <> ""
     THEN JULIANDAY(LAG( order_entry_date, 2 ) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id  ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC)) - JULIANDAY(LAG(order_entry_date,3) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC))
    END "order_interval_using_pvs3_order_date",
    
    CASE 
     WHEN LAG(order_entry_date,4) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC) <> ""
     THEN JULIANDAY(LAG( order_entry_date, 3 ) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id  ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC)) - JULIANDAY(LAG(order_entry_date,4) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY order_entry_date ASC))
    END "order_interval_using_pvs4_order_date"
    
) AS "Avg_ordr_interval",
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question#

Comment: Why do you have random identifiers like `"order_interval_using_pvs1_order_date"` in your expression? That's not valid syntax.

Comment: Ah, there is a very simple misunderstanding. AVG function goes over the whole of your selections, *not* over the arguments, not row by row. You have to do the calculation by hand, and this is a good thing, as no one ever can guess right fi and how you want the cases weighted.

Comment: -The four case functions product either a positive integer or null.  I have tested this.
- i have removed those random identifiers.  therefore this should compute to:

  AVG(integer, integer, integer, integer) AS "Avg_ordr_interval"

HOWEVER, i get error:  [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (wrong number of arguments to function AVG())

as per comment 3   i think i understand now.  avg cannot be used in this way.  thanks.   is there no sqlite function that can average four values as what i need?

Comment: Just do the calculation yourself, as in `((val1+val2+val3+val4)/4)'

Comment: Its just that sometimes val is null, and then the divisor needs to be one less.   ends up a nested case debacle.   the AVR takes care of this nicely, but works on columns not sub expressions as i have it.

Answer (score 0):

Create subquery getting previous rows values in the same row so you can do your own calculations of avverages. You can use Coalesce() function (in subquery) to handle null values.
With sample data like:

```sql
/*   c u s t o m e r s :
CUST_ID  CUST_NAME
-------  ----------
1        John
2        Jane
3        Mike       */
```

```sql
/*  o r d e r s :
ORD_ID  ORD_DATE    CUST_ID
------  ----------  -------
101     2023-07-15      1
102     2023-08-31      1
103     2023-11-11      1
131     2023-09-05      2
132     2023-11-17      2
151     2023-08-15      3
152     2023-09-08      3
153     2023-10-29      3
154     2023-11-30      3
155     2023-12-12      3       */
```

... use Case expressions to get just the values that exists (diffs > 0) for both, days and counts. Aggregate and group by...
SQL:

```sql
Select  CUST_ID, CUST_NAME,
        Round(   Sum(  ( Case When DAY_DIFF_1 > 0 Then DAY_DIFF_1 Else 0 End +
                         Case When DAY_DIFF_2 > 0 Then DAY_DIFF_2 Else 0 End +
                         Case When DAY_DIFF_3 > 0 Then DAY_DIFF_3 Else 0 End +
                         Case When DAY_DIFF_4 > 0 Then DAY_DIFF_4 Else 0 End 
                        ) 
                    )   /
                 Sum(   ( Case When DAY_DIFF_1 > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End +
                         Case When DAY_DIFF_2 > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End +
                         Case When DAY_DIFF_3 > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End +
                         Case When DAY_DIFF_4 > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End 
                        ) 
                    )   
            , 2) "AVG_DAYS"
From  ( Select    c.CUST_ID, c.CUST_NAME, 
                  o.ORD_DATE, 
                  JULIANDAY(o.ORD_DATE) - JULIANDAY(COALESCE(LAG(o.ORD_DATE, 1) Over(Partition By c.CUST_ID Order By o.ORD_DATE), o.ORD_DATE)) "DAY_DIFF_1", 

                  JULIANDAY(COALESCE(LAG(o.ORD_DATE, 1) Over(Partition By c.CUST_ID Order By o.ORD_DATE), o.ORD_DATE)) -
                  JULIANDAY(COALESCE(LAG(o.ORD_DATE, 2) Over(Partition By c.CUST_ID Order By o.ORD_DATE), o.ORD_DATE )) "DAY_DIFF_2", 

                  JULIANDAY(COALESCE(LAG(o.ORD_DATE, 2) Over(Partition By c.CUST_ID Order By o.ORD_DATE), o.ORD_DATE)) -
                  JULIANDAY(COALESCE(LAG(o.ORD_DATE, 3) Over(Partition By c.CUST_ID Order By o.ORD_DATE), o.ORD_DATE )) "DAY_DIFF_3", 

                  JULIANDAY(COALESCE(LAG(o.ORD_DATE, 3) Over(Partition By c.CUST_ID Order By o.ORD_DATE), o.ORD_DATE)) -
                  JULIANDAY(COALESCE(LAG(o.ORD_DATE, 4) Over(Partition By c.CUST_ID Order By o.ORD_DATE), o.ORD_DATE )) "DAY_DIFF_4"
            
        From        customers c
        Inner Join  orders o ON(o.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID)
        Order By    c.CUST_ID
      )
        Group By  CUST_ID, CUST_NAME
        Order By  CUST_ID, CUST_NAME
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
CUST_ID CUST_NAME   DAYS    CNT  AVG_DAYS
------- ---------  -------  ---  ---------
1       John         166      3    55.33
2       Jane          73      1       73
3       Mike         325     10     32.5    */
```

See it here --> https://dbfiddle.uk/fYrRJZqf
Note: This should be adjusted to your context. If I missunderstood the question, you can still use the same logic of getting all the data (needed to calculate your own average) in the same row first - and then use that data for calculations.

Comment: @d_R  thanks so much for going into this.   the results are exactly what I needed.   Revised it to my table field names and added some filters and viola.   Plus i learned couple things   again thanks.

Comment: @Regis You are wellcome. Glad to know it helped you.